# How to populate a Select taghelper in Razor using data from a SQL database table

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-1.0, tag-helpers

I'm using ASP.NET Core 1.0 and EF Core 1.0 and have the following code-first class in my SQL database.

```
namespace GigHub.Models
{
  public class Genre
  {
    public byte Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
}
```

I also have the following ViewModel class I use in a Razor view form:

```
namespace GigHub.ViewModels
{
  public class GigFormViewModel
  {
    public string Venue { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public List<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
  }
}
```

I also have this controller:

```
using GigHub.Data;
using GigHub.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace GigHub.Controllers
{
  public class GigsController : Controller
  {
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public GigsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
      _context = context;
    }
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
      var vm = new GigFormViewModel();

      // Need to get my Genre list from the DbSet<Genre> in my database context injected above
      // into the GigFormViewModel for the Select taghelper to consume

      return View(vm);
    }
  }
}
```

I have my Razor view set up to use the ViewModel fine but I'm unsure how the Select taghelper code below should be set up to access the Genre property.

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="????" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <select asp-for="????" asp-items="????" class="form-control"></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="????" class="text-danger" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

I'm basically having trouble grokking how to get my list of genres from my database into the ViewModel property in a form that the Select taghelper **asp-items=** can consume. The many trial & error contortions I've gone through generally result in conversion issues going from generic **List<>** type to MVCs **SelectListItem** type. I suspect my ViewModel Genre class needs adjusting but my research thus far has only resulted in articles covering previous versions of ASP.NET and Entity Framework and I struggle to map them to ASP.NET core 1.0 RC2 and EF Core 1.0.

Comment: `<select asp-for="FieldName"  asp-items="ViewBag.OptionsCollection"></select>`

Comment: Is there no way to avoid ViewBag and get the list from the ViewModel into list form for the taghelper along the lines of asp-items="Model.MyGenreListHere"?

Is this where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Simply use a field in your ViewModel. I'll post an example from ASP.NET documentation.

Comment: I suspect my root issue is going from List<Genre> from my ViewModel property to something like IEnumerable<SelectListItem> but the syntax eludes me. I still have much to learn about C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `asp-for` to specify the model property name for the select element and `asp-items` to specify the option elements.

```
<select asp-for="SomeFiles" asp-items="Model.SomeOptions"></select>
```

You can also use `ViewBag.SomeOptions` if you don't want to add the `SomeOptions` filed to the mode.

For more information take a look at [The Select Tag Helper](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/working-with-forms.html#the-select-tag-helper) documentation.

**Example**

*View*

```
<select asp-for="Country" asp-items="Model.Countries"></select>
```

*Model*

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FormsTagHelper.ViewModels
{
    public class CountryViewModel
    {
        public string Country { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*Controller*

The Index method initializes the `CountryViewModel`, sets the selected country and list of countries and passes the model to the Index view.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new CountryViewModel();
    model.Country = "CA";
    model.Countries = db.Countries
                        .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Id, Text = x.Name })
                        .ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I was going through that example on the docs site too but I could not mentally map it to my situation.

I already have my list of Genres stored in my domain model in the database so my ViewModel should have no need to initialise these elements by 'newing' them up to be used for the taghelper.

I was hoping in my controller to somehow use my database context to read the values from my DbContext<Genre> and map them to a property on my ViewModel but the syntax to avoid conversion issues eludes me.

Comment: Check the edited answer. You can simply convert data of a table to a `List<SelectListItem>` like above example.

Comment: Great. That appears to work and has gotten me back on track. It appears my 'Linq-Fu' could be better. Seems I need to hit up some more Linq tutorials to plug my knowledge gaps. Many thanks.

Comment: The odd thing is I assumed the Select taghelper acted like a dropdown but the rendered HTML is showing an already-expanded list of the entries from my database. Never mind, the head-scratching bit is solved and I'll just need to brush up on the taghelper behaviour to get it working like a drop down :)

Comment: As far as I know, it's equivalent to `Html.DropDownListFor`. But I don't have an environment to test it myself.